# NUnit build error 'Missing compiler required member System.Range.get_Start'

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nunit, restsharp

I'm trying to utilise NUNit and Newtonsoft JSON to make assertions against an API. I have a method which I am calling from another project in the solution and both projects are on .NET 4.7.2 and all NuGet packages are aligned in terms of version I believe, but I get the following error:

> CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Range.get_Start'

Oddly enough, I have called the same method elsewhere and have not received any build errors for it.

I've done some reading and it seems it could be something to do with DLLs but I have checked and I have the necessary DLLs references including Microsoft.CSharp and System.Core.

I've tried removing, re-adding reference and then building and even deleting the bin folder and re-building  - nothing seems to work.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: This exact error just started happening to me when I added Microsoft.Extensions.Http v2.1.1 to a .Net Core 2.1 Azure Function project. The problem resolved itself when the package was removed. Does that sound like it could be your issue?

Comment: I might add that I don't have NUnit installed or Newtonsoft.Json. My failure just appears on a seemingly random line of code: the open brace of one of my function methods. It's very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36178) which describes C# 8 features (in this case new indexing features) which are not properly suppressed.  In my case I had copy-pasted the wrong type in a method definition (`string` instead of `JObject`) and was trying to access it like this in the method:

```
public async Task PostFailureMessage([ActivityTrigger] string input)
{   // I got the error on this line

    string uri;

    // ...
    uri = input["failureURI"].ToString(); // trying to access as a JObject here
    // ...
}
```

The solution for me was to check the parameter types: `string` should have been `JObject`. The error message was altogether unhelpful in identifying the source of the problem.

Comment: I'm clearly blind, I was basically doing the same thing. I was trying to access IRestResponse's `Content` property as a list/dictionary, so I was calling it like `response["status"]`. I resolved this by using `JsonConvert.Deserialize<JObject>` and accessing it that way.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I forgot to add the link to the issue.  Added above.